# Strange anchor behavior

Tags: html

I have a link with href "#myanchor" on page say "http://test.com/mypage". It would move me to "http://test.com/mypage#myanchor", right?
But I have a problem with this anchor moves me to index page "http://test.com#myanchor".

Can you explain me why?

Thanks.

**EDIT**

Ha, I found some strange code on page:

```
var base = document.domain;
var port = window.location.port
document.write('<base href="http://' + base + (port?':':'') + port + '" />');
```

Problem is resolved.

@Surreal Dreams, if you want you may explain what is it, I'll choose your answer :)

Comment: Are you using .NET or anything? I need more context.

Comment: Could you post the markup that is giving you this result?

Comment: Do you have a `<base>` tag?  Again, please post your HTML so we can point out the actual error.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your link is not set to `href="/#myanchor"`?  This would cause you to target `http://test.com#myanchor`.

If you can show the actual HTML I can give you a more definite answer, but this is the likely cause.

Comment: Yep. <a href="#myanchor">Link</a>

Answer (score 0):

Cause, test.com is loading index.html by default. So test.com/#myanchor is the same as test.com/index.html#myanchor

Comment: He says he is doing this from http://test.com/mypage, not http://test.com/index.html.  He's right, it should load http://test.com/mypage#myanchor

Comment: Yes, but if he is doing his link odd, like you noted in your answer it would bounce him home.